# Does perceptron algorithm work for binary inputs?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

I tried to trace the Perceptron algorithm for logical "Or" with binary input (0,1) and binary output (0,1). But, it seems like that it doesn't work!

Here is my try:

```
x1   x2  w1 w2  bias  t   y
1    1   0  0   0     1   0   Update
1    0   1  1   1     1   1   OK   
0    1   1  1   1     1   1   OK
0    0   1  1   1     0   1   Update
1    1   1  1   1     1   1   OK
1    0   1  1   1     1   1   OK
0    1   1  1   1     1   1   OK
0    0   1  1   1     0   1   Update (but as before no updates occur)
```

My update rules are:

```
 Wi = Wi + xi*ti
 Bi = Bi + ti
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my update rule was very simple. The exact update rule must be:

```
 Wi = Wi + xi*(ti - yi)
 Bi = Bi + (ti - yi)
```

This change causes to have a `-1` for updating `b` when both `x1` and `x2` are zero:

```
x1   x2  w1 w2  bias  t   y   t-y
1    1   0  0   0     1   0   1    Update
1    0   1  1   1     1   1   0    OK   
0    1   1  1   1     1   1   0    OK
0    0   1  1   1     0   1   -1   Update
1    1   1  1   0     1   1   0    OK
1    0   1  1   0     1   1   0    OK
0    1   1  1   0     1   1   0    OK
0    0   1  1   0     0   1   0    OK
```